# How is this data format called (key="value")?

Tags: r, dataframe

RStudio user settings are written in the following text format (example of contents in a **text** file):

```sh
cranMirrorUrl="https://cran.rstudio.com/"
customShellCommand=""
customShellOptions=""
defaultTerminalShell="1"
showLastDotValue="0"
showUserHomePage="sessions"
uiPrefs="{\n    \"always_complete_characters\" : 2,\n    \"always_complete_console\" : true,\n    \"always_complete_delay\" : 250\n}"
vcsGitExePath=""
```

1. Does this format have a name? (The value of `uiPrefs` seems to be in JSON with `\n` and `\"` added.)
2. Are there any tools/packages in R to efficiently read this type of data into R list and, vice versa, write R list back into this format?

E.g., to read:

```sh
defaultTerminalShell="1"
showLastDotValue="0"
showUserHomePage="sessions"
```

Into something like:

```r
list(
  defaultTerminalShell = "1",
  showLastDotValue     = "0",
  showUserHomePage     = "sessions"
)
#> $defaultTerminalShell
#> [1] "1"
#> 
#> $showLastDotValue
#> [1] "0"
#> 
#> $showUserHomePage
#> [1] "sessions"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your data in this format

```
df<-c(cranMirrorUrl="https://cran.rstudio.com/",
customShellCommand="",
customShellOptions="",
defaultTerminalShell="1",
showLastDotValue="0",
showUserHomePage="sessions",
uiPrefs="{\n    \"always_complete_characters\" : 2,\n    \"always_complete_console\" : true,\n    \"always_complete_delay\" : 250\n}"
,vcsGitExePath="")
View(df)
```

This data structure defined can be used as a `vector`.

In order to read this data, Create an Excel or CSV file that contains this data in the column format and read the file and again write back the data into Excel or CSV file.

You can use `read.table()` - Reading the data and `write.table()`- Writing the data back into the file.

If there is a need to define it as a list then again you can convert it as `as.list()` and use the `sink()`  function to write back to the text file.